# Pagination using jqgrid for randomly changing data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jqgrid

I am developing a page in a application using Spring, hibernate. In that page I have to display records by fetching from database in a datatable using jqgrid. The problem at here is the records that  will be added to database in hundreds for every hour and total records in database is 300 000 and it's goes on increasing.  Now what is the best solution for this problem(in terms of pagination and loading data)?

Comment: here my question is can i keep that many huge records in cache? if yes give me an example if no the give me a solution for the  problem

Comment: Instead fetching all data at time use paging in hibernate criteria and display records according to page and number of records. Is there any problem with this solutions?

Comment: yes, If i fetch 10 records at first, then in second page I have to get next 10, but it gives new records because the records goes on inserting into db table in automation process

Comment: yes. Right you will get updated(or new records) then what is problem?

Comment: Then what about the old records which i have not seen? as records are coming hundred in numbers, then how can i process all the records by going though each record when a record processing takes 10 minutes...and one more thing is  i have got 10 records for first time, now assume that in the mean time 10 records are added to database , now when i click on 2nd page then also same viewed records will be displayed as 10 new records came to database, this is problem

Comment: are you  just adding new records or also updating or both?

Comment: both adding and updating

Comment: if you are adding records then it should be end of table. and sort data by primary when you retrieve data and display it. New records will added at end of table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for this.
store you data in session after retrieving from database and apply paging.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/support/PagedListHolder.html
I hop this will work.

Answer (score 0):

yes i got you problem. 
Twitter is also facing same problem to return tweets.
then solve this issue using **max_id** and **since_id**
here is documentation(flow) is there please refer it.
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines

You can apply same algorithm in your paging it will solve issue.
is this solve you issue?